# Gluon eclipse plugin - how to access the android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, javafx, javafxports

I am wondering how to access the android sdk to use android specific code in the src/android folders of the created Gluon JavaFX project.

I know that I can get the Android Context by using the `FXActivity` class.
But I can not import that nor classes of the Android SDK (e.g. `ActivityManager`).

I am using Eclipse Mars with the newest Gluon Plugin and the Android SDK Plugin installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added android.jar and jfxdvk.jar to the Eclipse build path manually but that is probably not the way it should be done. At least it works for the moment :-)

Comment: Thanks, didnt even think of that:)