# How to implemented in JAVAFX/Gluon a button to go to the default send Message for my Android Mobile

Tags: android, javafx, gluon-mobile

I have implemented a Button in my Mobile Application und have a Textfieldwith a Telefon Nummer.

What i want to achieve: When the User Click the Button-> The Default Page to send SMS is open in Android and the Telefonnummer is Paste in the default Nummer Textfield for Android.

I Use Gluon Mobile with JavaFX

```
:compileJava/Users/yotti/CAMVOYAGE/MultiViewProjectFXML/src/main/java/com/gluonapplication/views/AndroidSMSService.java:4: error: package android.content does not exist
import android.content.Intent;
                      ^
/Users/yotti/CAMVOYAGE/MultiViewProjectFXML/src/main/java/com/gluonapplication/views/AndroidSMSService.java:5: error: package android.net does not exist
import android.net.Uri;
                  ^
/Users/yotti/CAMVOYAGE/MultiViewProjectFXML/src/main/java/com/gluonapplication/views/AndroidSMSService.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
        ^
  symbol:   class Intent
  location: class AndroidSMSService
/Users/yotti/CAMVOYAGE/MultiViewProjectFXML/src/main/java/com/gluonapplication/views/AndroidSMSService.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
                               ^
  symbol:   class Intent
  location: class AndroidSMSService
/Users/yotti/CAMVOYAGE/MultiViewProjectFXML/src/main/java/com/gluonapplication/views/AndroidSMSService.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable Intent
  location: class AndroidSMSService
/Users/yotti/CAMVOYAGE/MultiViewProjectFXML/src/main/java/com/gluonapplication/views/AndroidSMSService.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
                          ^
  symbol:   variable Uri
  location: class AndroidSMSService
/Users/yotti/CAMVOYAGE/MultiViewProjectFXML/src/main/java/com/gluonapplication/views/AndroidSMSService.java:15: error: cannot access Activity
        FXActivity.getInstance().startActivity(smsIntent);
                  ^
  class file for android.app.Activity not found
7 errors
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at how the Charm Down plugins are [implemented](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down).

You will see that you can use most of the existing services without further modifications.

If the service you are looking for is not implemented yet, it is really easy to create it, following the same guidelines as the existing plugins:

On your source packages [Java], add the following classes:

Package: `com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins`. Class: `SMSService`:

```
package com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins;

public interface SMSService {
    void sendSMS(String number);
}
```

Package: `com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins`. Class: `SMSServiceFactory`:

```
package com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins;

import com.gluonhq.charm.down.DefaultServiceFactory;

public class SMSServiceFactory extends DefaultServiceFactory<SMSService> {

    public SMSServiceFactory() {
        super(SMSService.class);
    }

}
```

Finally, on the Android package, implement the service:

Package: `com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.android`, class: `AndroidSMSService`

```
package com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.android;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.SMSService;
import javafxports.android.FXActivity;

public class AndroidSMSService implements SMSService {

    @Override
    public void sendSMS(String number) {
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
        smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
        smsIntent.putExtra("address", number);
        FXActivity.getInstance().startActivity(smsIntent);
    }

}
```

*Test*

Now all you need to do is use the SMS service in your code, once you have the number added to the textField, and a button to fire the action:

```
Services.get(SMSService.class)
            .ifPresent(s -> button.setOnAction(e -> s.sendSMS(textField.getText())));
```

Build the application and deploy it to your Android device. Try it, and check that it opens the Messenger app (maybe it will ask to use other different apps), and already uses the provided number, so you can start typing your message.

Comment: Pereda  I try your Solution and adding compile group: 'com.google.android', name: 'android', version: '4.1.1.4' to Gradle . but i have this Error com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK resources.arsc. Is the dependency wrong?

Comment: Why do you add the android dependency?? It's already included by the jfxmobile plugin

Comment: When i remove it , i have this error package android.content does not exist. cannot find symbol
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

Comment: You are using Eclipse, aren't you? It fails to include the android compile dependencies.

Comment: Check this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596601/gluon-eclipse-plugin-how-to-access-the-android-sdk/33597086#33597086)

Comment: pereda. I have the Same Error After add this Jar . I have Update the Post

Comment: Make sure you add android.jar and jfxdvk.jar to the Eclipse path, so they can be found as external dependencies by the project.

Comment: Pereda. I have added it. But it not works. You can look The above Image

Comment: Are you adding the android class `AndroidSMSService` to the main package?? It has to go to the Android package `src/android/java/...`

Comment: @ Jose pereda. Yesterday i don't have errors. Because of than i thinked it works in android. I have not tested it yesterday. I deploy it in my android today. In the view I have enter a phone number, when I click the button to fire the Action, nothing is happen. It don't open the android default send sms view. Maybe you are forgot something. Are you have ideas why it not works?

Comment: Pereda do you have any ideas about this issue? I don't have any error. But the default sms manager, it not open

Comment: Is this already included in your Github project? So I can try to reproduce it.

Comment: No . I don't have Internet at this Moment. I push it tomorrow

Comment: Pereda I have included in my Github project . https://github.com/allipierre/CAMVOYAGE.git

Comment: You haven't used the packages I mentioned in my answer. Without that it won't work. Move the three referred classes to their packages (`com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins` on main and `com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.android` for the Android class).

Comment: pereda. Yes it works Fine now i Chance the packgage as you have said