# Image Filtering Application

Tags: javafxports, gluon-mobile

I want to create an image filtering application using gluon-mobile, I need to add android.graphics package, how can I do that, or Is there any other method...

Additionally, is there any way to access the image data with a high performance method, not like set pixel and get pixel.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? What have you tried and what is not working for you? Using Charm Down plugins you can native services for Android and iOS, and you can easily extend them, creating new services, that can provide your desired functionality accessing the Android API when required. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553087/how-to-implemented-in-javafx-gluon-a-button-to-go-to-the-default-send-message-fo/41579266#41579266) for instance.

Comment: @JoséPereda, I saw the example you mentioned, but actually I can't import android package at all in my application, so how can I do that.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the relevant code you are trying, and specify what errors you get when trying to import the android package?